# Modificar a opção "duplicata de..."

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Seria viável rever a opção de fechamento "Duplicata de" ?

Acho essa opção confusa muitas vezes pois acontece muito de existir perguntas diferentes cuja solução leva a uma mesma resposta.

Agora há pouco surgiu um caso: [Pegar id de uma gravação anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116632/pegar-id-de-uma-grava%C3%A7%C3%A3o-anterior)

Votei para fechar como "duplicata" dessa questão:

[Pegar o ID da última linha inserida no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89986/pegar-o-id-da-%C3%BAltima-linha-inserida-no-banco-de-dados/89992)

O problema aqui é que não são questões duplicadas. É conforme citei acima. São questões diferentes cuja solução leva a uma mesma resposta.

A sugestão seria adicionar uma opção do tipo

"Fechar" -> "Possível resposta em" -> [cola o link de uma resposta existente]

Comment: O termo "possível..." seria exibido naquela parte de baixo no comentário como acontece automaticamente quando vota para fechar. Exemplo: http://postimg.org/image/rmw0ki971/

Comment: rsrsr mas... "concesso"? não seria "consenso" ?

Comment: Meu português não é bão (JorgeB. que o diga), mas entendeu a intenção. De qualquer forma entendi melhor agora a sua proposta. Acho uma boa proposta, só tem um problema, tem perguntas que não tem resposta.

Comment: @DanielOmine nao como solução para o que vc disse, mas eu percebi esses dias que dá pra dois ou mais usuários indicarem diferentes originais pra duplicata. Com um pouco de coordenação, dá pra matar algumas semi-duplicatas apontando 2 soluções que se complementam.

Comment: O termo "semi-duplicata" ficou bacana!

Comment: Só pra constar fui eu quem deu o upvote, agora quem deu downvote eu não sei.

Comment: Se a resposta é exatamente a mesma, tenho a impressão que são sim a mesma pergunta, mas realizadas de forma diferente (possivelmente em virtude do problema XY). Qual seria a vantagem de criar um novo mecanismo, mas que teria o mesmo resultado (concentrar o foco em uma resposta (ou várias) apenas, evitando coisas duplicadas (mesmo que só a resposta))?

Comment: a questão aqui é o termo usado. Quando vota para fechar, fica como “pergunta duplicata” mas na prática as perguntas possuem teor diferente, o tal do “problema XY”.` ou “semi duplicada”. Com isso alguns usuários discordam e reclamam dizendo que a pergunta é diferente e não entende que a resposta da “duplicata” é a base. Por isso a sugestão em fazer algo mais “refinado”. Ao invés de “pergunta duplicata de...”, apresentar opção como o sugerido. Como recurso novo no mecanismo, não é algo que traria mudança drástica e deve ser simples implementar.

Comment: Eu sou a favor de "renomear" os termos usados na duplicata pra referenciar as respostas, em vez de dizer que a pergunta é duplicata. "Esta pergunta já tem uma resposta em: [link]". Assim, o foco fica na solução e não na forma de descrever o problema (que algumas vezes é usada pra "disfarçar" uma duplicata cuja resposta "não agradou" quem quer outro caminho, mas não quer gastar no _bounty_).

Comment: Dando um up para mostrar como esse assunto é relevante:  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5828