# Quando alguém fala "Possível duplicata de..."

Tags: debate

Eu tenho percebido que essa simples frase

**"Possível duplicata de..."**

Pode acabar em um terrível engano. Eu percebo isso quando certas perguntas recebem esse aviso e autor da pergunta se irrita. Dizendo que não acha que a sua pergunta seja vinculada a outra. Outras vezes temos autores que agradecem, pois assim pode-se formar uma árvore de termos, facilitando a busca pela comunidade.

A minha discussão, a minha indagação seria: **É necessário comentar dessa forma?**

Eu não crítico quem faz isso, apenas estou sugerindo uma mudança, na qual a comunidade tenha visão em saber quando a pergunta foi repetida e quando ela está relacionada a outra. **Deixando bem claro que o usuário, na verdade fez algo bom.**

A pergunta dele que já foi respondida poderá atrair mais soluções e irá facilitar a busca dessas soluções por usuários novos.

Comment: O sistema faz isto.

Comment: @bigown então é falta de atenção do usuário? Talvez seja melhor trabalhar a interface? Porque é fato que tem discussões e não deve ser raro ver usuários que abandonam a vontade de fazer perguntas por um mal entendido.

Comment: Eu não vejo problema nesta frase, e ela diz `Possível Duplicata` ou seja, pode ser uma duplicata, ela não afirma, `É uma duplicata da pergunta tal...`

Comment: @gato por isso eu afirmei que é um terrível engano. A visão humana censura palavras positivas e dão destaques as palavras negativas.  Eles podem ver  `Duplicata` como algo negativo inconcientemente.

Comment: Como não sou especialista em UX não tenho opinião formada, eu sei que pra mim a frase está ok, mas eu talvez seja um ponto fora da curva.

Comment: Isso é uma questão de UX. Abordei sobre isso nesse tópico que ficou sem resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4924/modificar-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-duplicata-de

Comment: @AsuraKhan eu já tinha proposto esta mudança já no post original do Omine: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4924/modificar-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-duplicata-de#comment17705_4924 - Ele havia dito sobre a razão de fechamento, e a minha proposta foi exatamente mudar o termo final, que era o que o autor da pergunta lê. Ficando algo como "Esta pergunta já tem uma resposta em: ", parece mais como caminho para a solução do que "queixa" ao autor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz essa mesma pergunta em 2016: [Modificar a opção "duplicata de..."](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4924), porém, ficou sem resposta.

Eu poderia marcar isso aqui como duplicada? rs..

## Frase automática

Conforme o @VictorStafusa esclareceu, a frase é automática, gerada pelo sistema.

Particularmente, eu não acho que o sistema deveria incluir o nome da pessoa dessa forma. A primeira vez que vi meu nome num desses comentários automáticos tive uma má impressão, do tipo "como que postam uma frase em meu nome?". Claro que na hora entendi que era algo automático. Mas mesmo assim não acho isso certo. Tudo bem o post automático, mas sem colocar o nome da pessoa. Um dos motivos de ocultar o nome explico mais abaixo, além de ser algo "invasivo".

## UX

Uma simples mudança nos termos do comentário automático reduziriam o mal entendido.

O ponto aqui é UX (User Experience).

Isso é algo recorrente e sempre os menos experientes no uso do site fazem má interpretação. E eu não tiro a razão deles pois o próprio site os induz a essa situação.

Conforme sugeri na p[ergunta do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4924), poderia apenas mudar o termo "**Possível duplicata de...**" para algo como "**Possível resposta: [link]**".

Para quem ainda não consegue enxergar o problema, é simples. O usuário posta uma pergunta com um contexto diferente do link marcado como  "Possível duplicata" e logo fica nervoso por achar que está sendo censurado, sabotado ou coisa do tipo. E **normalmente quem leva o "ferro" é a pessoa que marcou a duplicada** pois a frase mal colocada vem acompanhada do nome da pessoa. O sujeito, que já está nervoso, associa a ação ao nome da pessoa que o sistema colocou automaticamente.

Isso gera um mal estar desnecessário entre os membros do site.

É um detalhe sutil.

Para quem é mais experiente e está acostumado como o site funciona, pode parecer irrelevante, mas particularmente acredito ser uma falha de UX.

Comigo isso é recorrente. Já passei por casos onde o AP ou quem postou resposta  vem ofender e possivelmente sai negativando em tudo posteriormente.

Espero que a administração tome alguma providência ao invés de apenas negativar  a sugestão ou deixar abandonada.

Somente quem pode editar os textos do sistema é que pode resolver.

Comment: Daniel Parabéns, você matou a discussão. É justamente isso que eu quis dizer. Você percebeu que é um detalhe sútil que pode até mesmo levar ao usuário a abandonar o stackoverflow.

Eu mesmo, na primeira vez que eu entrei no Stackoverflow, eu tomei uma sinalização de duplicata e só voltei ao site depois de 6 meses. 

Me senti tipo " eu não achei essa pergunta/resposta, é culpa minha?"

Sua sugestão de alterar para **Possível resposta: [link]** é genial, iria matar o problema na mesma hora. Ninguém iria se sentir ofendido.

Comment: Na minha opinião, o problema com "Possível resposta" é que talvez a pergunta duplicada não tenha resposta.

Comment: @EMBarbosa nesse caso não dá pra votar fechamento da pergunta. (creio que uma exceção seria 2 do mesmo autor).

Answer (score 7):

Se você tiver reputação suficiente, quando você for fechar uma pergunta, você começa clicando neste link:

<kbd>[image: Link de fechar]</kbd>

E então, vai surgir essa tela:

<kbd>[image: Tela de fechar]</kbd>

Se eu escolher a opção "*duplicata de...*", chego nesta outra tela:

<kbd>[image: Escolhendo a duplicata]</kbd>

Nesta tela, eu posso escolher qual é a questão que considero ser a original, a fim de fechar como duplicata. Após isso ser feito e eu clicar no botão "Votar para fechar", o meu voto de fechamento é dado.

Mas, sempre que alguém vota para fechar algo como duplicata, **o sistema cria 
automaticamente um comentário na pergunta** em nome desta pessoa com o texto "*Possível duplicata de...*".

Se/quando uma outra pessoa que for votar para fechar, também escolher duplicata e escolher a mesma pergunta na duplicata, o sistema vai colocar automaticamente um upvote no comentário de duplicata postado anteriormente.

Ou seja, esses comentários que você considera irritantes são apenas comentários postados automaticamente. Assim sendo, a resposta ao seu questionamento acerca de "*É necessário comentar dessa forma?*" é que as pessoas que o fazem muitas vezes nem sequer notam que o sistema está postando esses comentários em seu nome.

Por outro lado, se não houvesse comentário automático nenhum, isso seria ainda pior, uma vez que o comentário serve como um aviso de que alguém votou para fechar a pergunta como duplicata, e ainda por cima diz quem foi essa pessoa. Além disso, há muita gente que fecha perguntas sem comentar nada, problema esse minimizado por esse comentário automático forçado. Esse comentário também te dá a oportunidade de responder com um "@fulano" nos comentários da pergunta para tentar convencer a pessoa que não é duplicata ou para tentar entender as razões que a levaram a pensar isso.

Entretanto, se o seu questionamento é o de apenas mudar o texto padrão do comentário para algo que tenha menor chance de ser mal interpretado ou de irritar o usuário, aí basta sugerir um texto melhor e o pessoal que [trabalha na tradução do site](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/dashboard/) pode dar um jeito.

Comment: O comentário também é inserido ao sinalizar uma pergunta como duplicada