# Sistema orientar "automaticamente" usuários em perguntas duplicatas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Isto é uma sugestão que vai além do SOpt, é o seguinte, as vezes marco uma pergunta como duplicata e o AP reclama que a resposta lá não resolve o problema dele, notei que os APs com tais tipos de atitude nem sempre reclamam por mal, na verdade creio que as pessoas costumam olhar somente a primeira resposta (não tenho certeza), as vezes uma resposta sem pontos é o que resolve o problema do AP e justifica a duplicata, atualmente o sistema mostra assim:

> [image: atual]

A minha sugestão é que os comentários gerados automaticamente e o elemento que destaca as duplicatas deveriam ter uma mensagem mais clara de orientação, seria algo mais ou menos assim (é apenas uma sugestão, quem ler pode responder com outras sugestões):

> [image: sugestão]

---

### Comentários gerados automaticamente

Os comentários gerados são como:

> Possível duplicata de [Como salvar o dia de hoje no banco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91415/como-salvar-o-dia-de-hoje-no-banco)

Isto me parece que dá o entendimento que a "pergunta" justifica a duplicata, o que nem sempre é o caso, muitas vezes é uma das respostas que justifica a duplicata, eu creio que os comentários gerados pelo sistema poderiam ser algo mais ou menos assim (é apenas uma sugestão, podem sugerir outras):

> Possível duplicata, existem 6 respostas em [Como salvar o dia de hoje no banco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91415/como-salvar-o-dia-de-hoje-no-banco), talvez uma delas resolva o seu problema

---

Creio que facilitar o entendimento dos usuários sobre que *qualquer resposta* pode lhe ser útil na pergunta linkada pode lhe ser útil, não só a marcada como correta, isto ajudaria muito a evitar problemas, afinal o AP chega aqui sem entender o funcionamento do site, no que pudermos facilitar só vejo benefícios.

Comment: Eu acho que o sistema precisa orientar muito mais e muito melhor ao usuário, principalmente novato, começando por essas sugestões.

Comment: "Automatizar" é o caminho :D

Comment: Gostei. As sugestões são bem viáveis, basta alterarmos traduções no transifex.

Comment: @bfavaretto legal, vou só esperar ver se alguém tem sugestões de textos melhores, quanto mais intuitivo melhor

Comment: Assuntos relacionados: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4924 e  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5828

Comment: @bfavaretto Será que a gente consegue fazer essa quebra de linha pela _string_ do transifex?

Comment: @LINQ Não sei, podemos tentar um `<br>` e ver se dá certo ou será escapado...

Comment: O problema, eu acho, é que iria ficar um bom tempo com este `<br>` se for escapado. Porque geralmente demora uns dias pra _string_ ser revisada, importada e aí tem que esperar a publicação do site.

Comment: @LINQ tem outro problema, perguntas com mais de um dup formariam repetições do texto, vou ter que sugerir algo diferente, o que sugeri mesmo que quiséssemos não vai funcionar :/

Comment: É, eu pensei nisso quando vi aquela multi-dup de ontem

Comment: Acho que ao invés de "Possível duplicata, existem 6 respostas em Como salvar o dia de hoje no banco?, talvez uma delas resolva o seu problema" poderia ser melhor fazer um link direto para a resposta que se acredita que resolverá o problema, como "Uma possível solução para sua Pergunta pode ser <link>esta resposta</link>, por favor verifique se esta resposta soluciona sua Pergunta". Mas isso poderia exigir relacionar uma resposta de outra pergunta como solução, teria que adicionar funcionalidade ao site, é mais inviável.

Comment: @Douglas isto vai além de ajustar a tradução, o que você propõe é impossivel a curto prazo, só falando com a empresa Stack Overflow (que vai além do sopt, soen, sorusso, sojapones, etc).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então talvez a maneira mais prática seja, além de marcar como possível duplicada fazendo aparecer essa mensagem, adicionar um comentário dizendo qual Resposta acredita-se resolver a pergunta, isso evita que o usuário tenha que procurar entre as respostas (e talvez desistir rapidamente antes de ler todas). Isto é viável? Daria pra automatizar com algo usado pelos moderadores, como uma extensão no navegador, robô, ou outra coisa que não dependa da empresa Stack Overflow implementar?

Comment: @Douglas a questão aqui é resolver dentro do possivel com o que temos disponivel e ajudar a melhorar a experiencica de maneira mais automatizada possivel, que é ajustar os textos no sistema ["Transifex"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/3635).

Answer (score 5):

Concordo fortemente com a ideia. Quanto mais claro para os novatos for a forma como o SO funciona, menos trabalho a gente terá para manter o stack limpo e bonito. Segue apenas minha sugestão de alternativa para o texto:

> Esta pergunta já tem uma boa resposta aqui:
>   [Link para a pergunta aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6099/sistema-orientar-automaticamente-usu%C3%A1rios-em-perguntas-duplicatas)
>
> **Se você acha que a resposta da pergunta indicada acima não tem a solução para a sua dúvida,** edite a sua pergunta para indicar como o seu problema é diferente daquele da outra pergunta.

E no comentário automático:

> Possível duplicata de [outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6099/sistema-orientar-automaticamente-usu%C3%A1rios-em-perguntas-duplicatas), que já possui uma resposta marcada como correta. Verifique se essa pergunta já possui a solução que você procura.

Eu acho que indicar ao usuário que ele deve ler todas as respostas não é um bom ponto, pois nós focamos em ter uma única resposta certa e ideal para cada pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, não estou certo, mas a primeira sugestão me pareceu meio confusa, ao menos para quem é iniciante no site. Sobre a sugestão do comentário, eu não concordo, porque nem sempre a resposta marcada como correta é o que atenderá a pessoa, um exemplo é esta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213519/3635 aonde marquei como dup devido a 2 respostas que não são as marcadas como corretas: [Diego Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91416/3635) e [Ivan Ferrer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91444/3635), creio que o ideal é explicar que todas respostas podem ser úteis.

Comment: Só discordo dessa parte: "eu acho que indicar ao usuário que ele deve ler todas as respostas não é um bom ponto, pois nós focamos em ter uma única resposta certa e ideal para cada pergunta." - isto não é fato, queremos várias boas respostas para a pergunta, sempre que possível. Inclusive, a recomendação era de 2.5:1